# Swift: UIImage -- Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, ios8, uiimage

Below is the code that I'm using to build an array of images

```
var _displayImage : Array<UIImage>!

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self._displayImage = []
}

func buildImageSet() {
    self._displayImage = [UIImage(named: "image1"), UIImage(named: "image2"), UIImage(named: "image3"), UIImage(named: "image4"), UIImage(named: "image5")]
}
```

I get an error:  Could not find an overload for 'init' that accepts the supplied arguments

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you declared your array like this:

```
var _displayImage : Array<UIImage>!
```

So it is expecting `UIImage` objects.  The problem is that `UIImage(named:String)` returns a `UIImage?` optional.  The quick fix is to switch this:

```
func buildImageSet() {
    self._displayImage = [UIImage(named: "image1"), UIImage(named: "image2"), UIImage(named: "image3"), UIImage(named: "image4"), UIImage(named: "image5")]
}
```

To this:

```
func buildImageSet() {
    self._displayImage = [UIImage(named: "image1")!, UIImage(named: "image2")!, UIImage(named: "image3")!, UIImage(named: "image4")!, UIImage(named: "image5")!]
}
```

Although this doesn't account for the possibility that any of these images might be `nil`.  If any of the images don't load properly, your application will crash.  If you're sure they all exist and will always exist, this should be fine. :)